# Do I need to visitor pattern in my design

Tags: design-patterns, c++

I am working on designing HTML parser for study purpose. Where I am first creating an overall design.

Data structure to store HTML element.

`Base` : HtmlBaseElement

`Derived` : HTMLElement, PElement, HtagElemement, ImgElement, BodyElement, StrongElement

Basically, I will create a derived class for each type of element in HTML.

I need to write this HTML file back to a file and allow user to add the element in the already parsed HTML file.

This is what I am thinking :

First Approach:

1. Create a `BaseVisitor` which is having visit function for each type of element.
2. Create a Derived Visitor Class `WriteHtmlVisitor` to write the whole file which will `visit` each element in HTML datastructure.

Second Approach:

I can also use a class `WriteHtmlFile` , having object of `HTMLElement` and then write this using getter of all elements.

Which is the best way to write HTML file and adding new elements in file.

I am just looking for a suggestion, as this is in the design phase.

Thanks.

Comment: This is more a question for Software Engineering Stack Exchange! Sorry to bounce this round... https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Persixty when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat A fair point but in this case it's been referred from Computer Science rather than cross posted. It seems the option in a close vote to cross refer isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your layout of the visitor would work and in plugins for IntelliJ IDEA we use this all the time.

To give a concrete example: In IDEA we have kind of an abstract syntax tree of the code in the editor. Using a *recursive* visitor, you can turn each element into its string representation and the work is distributed to many small and easy to understand methods. Each `visitXXX` just turns a small portion to a string and calls the `visit` method recursively.

The advantage is that this is easy to understand and to debug. The only disadvantage I ever experienced is that you need a visit method for all your element types in base-class. However, once set-up, it works like a charm.

I can give you Java code to look at and although it's IDEA specific, it should be clear enough to understand it. [Here is the base class](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-IntelliJ-Plugin/blob/develop/src/de/halirutan/mathematica/lang/psi/MathematicaVisitor.java) for the visitor defining methods for all possible elements. And [here is an example](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-IntelliJ-Plugin/blob/develop/src/de/halirutan/mathematica/lang/psi/util/MathematicaFullFormCreator.java) of what you have in mind: a visitor that turns elements into a string representation.

Hope this helps and you don't mind the Java code.